# Drawing TLC Plates in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

So I am trying to create the following image:
[image]

It was going smoothly, but then I couldn't figure out how to place in the words and the dots. I tried using the node but it produced something huge and I could not get it to become smaller. Please let me know and thank you.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm,box/.style = {draw, very thick, minimum width=7em,minimum height=14em}]
\node (n1) [box,path picture={\coordinate (A) at (0.75,-1.75);
                        \draw[dotted] (-1.5,-1.75)--(1.5,-1.75);
                        \node at (A) [circle,fill,inner sep=0.0005pt]{};
                        }]{};
\node (n2) [box,right=of n1,path picture={\draw[dotted] (-1.5,-1.75)--(1.5,-1.75);}]{};
\node (n3) [box,right=of n2,path picture={\draw[dotted] (-1.5,-1.75)--(1.5,-1.75);}]{};
\node (n4) [box,right=of n3,path picture={\draw[dotted] (-1.5,-1.75)--(1.5,-1.75);}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put a node in a `path picture` of another node, you have key inheritance problem, similarly to what happens when nesting `tikzpicture`s. An IMHO much cleaner way is to use `pic`s. You can control the parameters by pgf keys, which you can set on the fly. In addition, it is worthwhile to set up local coordinate systems in which the bottom-left corner of the boxes is `(0,0)` and the top-right corner `(1,1)`. Then it is much more intuitive to place these dots. They can be smuggled into the `pic`s with `extra/.code={...}`. Finally, the relative positioning of the `pic`s can be done with a `\matrix`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,inner
    sep=1.5pt,fill=black},wullet/.style={circle,inner
    sep=1.2pt,fill=white},font=\sffamily,
    pics/container/.style={code={
            \tikzset{container/.cd,#1}%
            \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/container/##1}}%
            \begin{scope}[shift={(-\pv{w}/2,-\pv{h}/2)},x=\pv{w},y=\pv{h}]
            \fill[gray!40] (0,0) rectangle (1,\pv{p});
            \draw[densely dotted] (0,\pv{l}) -- (1,\pv{l});
            \draw[very thick] (0,0) 
            rectangle (1,1);
            \path (0.5,1) node[below]{\pv{text}};
            \pgfkeys{/tikz/container/extra}
            \end{scope}
}},container/.cd,w/.initial=7em,h/.initial=14em,p/.initial=0,l/.initial=0.12,
text/.initial={},extra/.code={}]
 \matrix[column sep=1em] (mat) {
 \pic{container={p=0.1,text=initial,extra/.code={
    \path (1/4,\pv{l}) node[bullet=black](b1){} (3/4,\pv{l}) node[bullet](b2){}; 
    }}};
 & \pic{container={p=0.2,text=10 minutes,extra/.code={
    \path (1/4,0.1) node[bullet=black](b3){} (3/4,0.14) node[bullet](b4){}; 
    }}};
 & \pic{container={p=0.65,text=30 minutes,extra/.code={
    \path (1/4,0.2) node[wullet](b5){} (1/4,0.21) node[bullet](b6){} 
    (3/4,0.24) node[bullet](b7){} (3/4,0.22) node[wullet](b8){}; 
    }}};
 & \pic{container={p=0.85,text=final,extra/.code={
    \path (1/4,0.3) node[wullet](b9){} (1/4,0.35) node[bullet](b10){} 
    (3/4,0.7) node[bullet](b11){} (3/4,0.6) node[wullet](b12){}; 
    }}};
 \\};
 \path[nodes={align=left,font=\tiny}]
  (mat.south west) node[anchor=south east,xshift=-1em] (p1) {Mobile\\ Phase}
  node[above=1em of p1] (p2){Sample\\ Mixture};
 \path[nodes={align=right,font=\tiny}]
  (mat.south east) node[anchor=south west,xshift=1em,yshift=3em] 
  (p3) {Some\\ long\\ text}
  node[above=1em of p3] (p4){Some\\ long\\ text};
 \draw (p1) -- (b1) (p2) -- (b2) (p3) -- (b12) (p4) -- (b11); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]